# Prevent Flatlist from scrolling when new items are added

Tags: react-native

When adding data to the Flatlist (e.g. subscriptions) it scrolls down leading to a very bad UX.
Any idea on how this could be solved?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I think this must be handled in native level, but not handled yet,
I solve my problem by saving scroll offset and set it again after reloading data like this:

```
reloadData(flatListData){

   this.setState({
       flatListData: flatListData
   });

   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
         this.flatList.scrollToOffset({
                       animated: false,
                       offset: this.flatListLastOffset
             });
   });
}
```

...

```
<FlatList
     data={this.state.flatListData}
     ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
     onScroll={(event: Object) => {
           this.flatListLastOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
           }}
     horizontal={false}
     scrollEventThrottle={16}
 />
```

this is not the best solution, but can fix my problem for now

Comment: Did you find better solution?

Comment: Thank your for your answer Amir jan, but this solution comes with a poor user experience and is not general. I posted a more general question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241572/flatlist-keep-position-when-new-item-is-added